# Marketing Cloud tracking data into Sales Cloud and Analytics Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-analytics, jitterbit

I'm investigating ways to get Marketing Cloud tracking information into Analytics Cloud.  Marketing Cloud Connect is installed, but *all Marketing Activity is initiated and takes place in Marketing Cloud.  Very little action happening in Sales Cloud.*

In general, the client wants data to flow from outside sources -> Sales Cloud -> Analytics Cloud.  So dataflow is being used to bring it into Analytics Cloud, and middleware to get it into Sales Cloud.

In the past, Ive successfully used Jitterbit to bring the data directly in Analytics Cloud.   But for arguments sake, let's say that bringing it into Sales Cloud is required this time.

What would be the least resource expensive way to bring in the tracking data?  The client is going to want to do analyses and drill into results in Wave, but adding almost 500K rows of data per month into Sales Cloud seems like an unsustainable path (am I incorrect in thinking that?).

My thinking is that I should bring in the Account Sends, Opens, Bounces, Unsubs data, and create some corresponding custom objects with lookups to the contact and each other.  The account sends should have some of the higher level data, and the others can be reflected at the contact level.

Is this approach sustainable?  Is there a problem with it that I'm not anticipating?  Is there a far better way to do this?

Comment: What is the use of putting it in Sales Cloud if the only place you are interacting with the data is in Analytics Cloud? You are correct that 500k rows per month could get expensive quickly. That will eat up ~ 1 GB/month worth of storage.

Comment: I agree with you.   I'm not sure why the design is set up that way.  Only thing I can think of is if they wanted to do some kind of triggers or something before sending the data along.  But the only use I can think of is for triggers to somehow work on the data to do something to reduce its size.

At which point, you're back to the question of why bother putting it in Sales Cloud in the first place?

Comment: Marketing Cloud Connect can be configured to automatically  send tracking data back to Sales Cloud.  But, only tracking data for emails that were iniitiated from Sales Cloud or via the Salesforce Email Activity in Marketing Cloud.

Comment: The second part of your statement is new information to me.   The Salesforce Email activity can send tracking data back?   Is there documentation around this?

I think that, either way, it isn't really valuable for the customer to be holding this data in Salesforce.  The original solution design had us sending the data into SF through Ampscript and then pulled into Analytics cloud.   I am going to keep questioning if this is good for anyone and whether they would be better off using an established middleware solution as opposed to pushing it into Sales Cloud to use dataflow.